# Update IBOutlet on Main View from Sub View

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview, iboutlet

I have a main view which has a UISlider on it.

From the main view I add a subview using:

```
gameView *myViewController = [[gameView alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

The subview is created on top of the main view.

When I remove the sub view using:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

the main view underneath becomes visible.

I want to be able to update the value of the UISlider on the main view, from the sub view, before I call [self.view removeFromSuperview]

Is it possible?

Basically the question can be generalized to how to update an IBOutlet on the main view from the sub view.

Help is greatly appreciated. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

And there's a few ways to do this. Here's how I would do it:

First, make your parent view controller's `UISlider` a property that can be accessed by other objects.

Secondly, give your `gameView` object an instance variable that you'll link to the parent view (let's call it `id savedParent;`)

Then, before you do `removeFromSuperview`, you can simply do something like:

```
ParentViewController * parentVC = (ParentViewController *) savedParent;
if(parentVC)
{
    // some float value of whatever you want to set the slider value to
    parentVC.slider.value = 0.5f; 
}
```

Also, why are you instantiating a whole View Controller object (`gameView`) if you simply want to add a subview?  When you do your `removeFromSubview` call, the view gets removed but your `gameView` view controller isn't released (and might even be getting lost & leaked in memory, leading to a crash).  If you want to do a subview, subclass `UIView`.  If you want to push a new view controller, push the whole controller (and not just the view it contains).

Comment: Hi @Michael - thanks a lot for the advise not to use another View Controller. I didn't know how to do it, so I followed this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzMorvFTHLM&feature=related 
Now I found one that uses the presentModalViewController here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GeazgOqKJ4 - hopefully that's the right way to do the transition.

Comment: So @Michael - back to my question please:
1. How do I make my UISlider a property that can be accessed by other objects?
2. How do I give my gameView object an instance variable and how do  I'll it link to the parent view (let's call it id savedParent;)
Sorry about so many / detailed questions. Many thanks!

Comment: this is not working. I've implemented like you said. It doesn't give me any errors, but doesn't update the slider either. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

I'm not sure what the slider is representing, but you need to create an object that represents this

```
@interface MyGameThing : NSObject
@property (assign) CGFloat myValue;
@end 

@implementation MyGameThing {
   CGFloat *_value;
}
@synthesize myValue = _myValue;
@end
```

You then need to pass that object to both of your view controllers (or make it a singleton).

Then, on ParentViewController, in the viewWillAppear, just set the slider to the new value.

Daniel.

(p.s. don't just add view controllers views to the superview, use presentModalViewController / dismissModalViewController or a navigation controller).

Comment: Hi @dorada - as per my comments above, thanks very much for the advise not to add view controllers. I was just following a video tutorial. I'll try with using the presentModalViewController as advised. Cheers!

Comment: I used this:
 `gameView *myViewController = [[gameView alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameView" bundle:nil];
 
 myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 
 [self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
 
 [myViewController release];`

it worked very well. I hope that's the right way to do it, isn't it?